# How to mix two asp.net projects: WebForms for backend and MVC for frontend on the same domain?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, frontend, backend

We are developing an application and want to separate it into two projects. The first project for end users will be on asp.net mvc, and the second for administration will be on asp.net webforms because simple crud operations perform easier on webforms and there are many out of the box controls. Problems:

1. share same authentication system
2. access to backend via site.com/backend

Answer (score 3):

Piece of cake.

1. The backbone of Authentication is part of Asp.net's core.  MVC and WebForms share things like the FormsAuthentication cookies and [Membership Providers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.aspx)
2. WebForms and MVC get along just fine.  All you really need to do is set `routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;` in global.asax for your /backend/ subdirectory and MVC won't try and route your WebFormPages.aspx to Controllers.

Comment: I meant in question two separate projects. In one mvc project mixing with webforms as you said is indeed piece of cake

Answer (score 0):

**cause simple crud operations performs easer on webforms**

I don't agree with this at all.  You have the same problems with either or unless you're going to use SQLdatasource which I don't recommend.  nHibernate and EntityFramework provide a nice data access solution for both webforms and mvc

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274688/using-one-asp-net-membership-database-with-multiple-applications-single-sign-on) is a link to how I achieved Single Sign On, two asp.net projects pointing to the same membership schema.

Answer (score 0):

Why are crud operations easier on webforms? MVC in my opinion is better for crud operations out of the box. Also try jquery controls, as they are better than the built in ASP.NET controls.