# Use different Membership Provider and Role Provider programmatically at runtime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership

I am using SQL server2012 database in with default ASP.net Membership. I have To Applications in the aspnet_applications table.

Let **A** and **B**

From One application in the Web Project i am creating user for the second Application.which will store in the aspnet_users table

Let From Application **A** from web i am creating the user for Application **B**

using the following code

```
Membership.ApplicationName = "B";
MembershipUser user = Membership.CreateUser(username, Membership.GeneratePassword(7, 2), email);
```

And after creting this new user i am not able to access the Current Application (Application A) until i restart the project.

So what is the problem here?

How can i add user to another application ?

Thanks

Comment: To achieve this, please can you follow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274688/using-one-asp-net-membership-database-with-multiple-applications-single-sign-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Membership.ApplicationName = "B";` means you switch the application name in runtime.

Actually, you want to call a provider by name. Then create a user using the provider.

```
MembershipProvider membershipProvider = 
    Membership.Providers["BMembershipProvider"];

Guid userId = Guid.NewGuid();

MembershipCreateStatus status;

membershipProvider.CreateUser("johndoe", "password", 
    "johndoe@email.com", "question", "answer", true, userId, out status);

if (status == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
{
    MembershipUser user = membershipProvider.GetUser(userId, false);

    // Optional - assign the user to roles
    RoleProvider roleProvider = Roles.Providers["SiteBRoleProvider"];
    roleProvider.AddUsersToRoles(new[] {user.UserName}, new[] {"Admin"});
}
```

Make sure you have both Membership Providers in **web.config**

```
<membership defaultProvider="AMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <add name="AMembershipProvider" 
          type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider ..." 
          connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" ... />
    <add name="BMembershipProvider"
          type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider ..."
          connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" ... />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it works for me.... Now i am struck at Roles I am getting Roles As  

      Roles.ApplicationName = "B";
           Roles.GetAllRoles().ToList(); also i am saving the user in role as
        Roles.ApplicationName = "B";
        Roles.AddUserToRole(userName, roleName);

So how can i implement this because in member ship provider there is no any Roles methods