# Asp.net Membership - Login from different asp.net application folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, membership

If have got an asp.net website with the following structure, the root used to be plain HTML and all .aspx pages where in a subfolder application. In the subfolder application, members are able to login via the asp.net membership, but not able to do this from the homepage.

**Ideal solutions:**

I would like visitors to be able to login from the homepage, rather then just from the subfolder.

**Current setup:**

The root of the website contains a web.config file with asp.net membership configuration, The form settings are pointing to a (sub) folder within the same website:

in the **root** web.config I have:

```
 <forms name="aspnetUsers" loginUrl="SUBFOLDER/account/login.aspx" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

in the **root / subfolder** web.config I have:

```
 <forms name="aspnetUsers" loginUrl="~/account/login.aspx" timeout="43200" cookieless="UseCookies" />
```

**Problem:**

I'm able to click on the Login link of Login control on the homepage, which will take me to `root / subfolder / account / login.aspx`, but after login, I return to the Homepage in the root folder and the Login control doesn't recognizes me as being logged in, however when I browse to a page within the `root / subfolder` I'm logged in?

How I can best deal with this problem?

Comment: Thanks halfer, for the corrections

Answer (score 0):

This question might be a duplicate and can be closed, as I have found the solution on StackOverflow here:

[Using one Asp.net Membership database with multiple applications Single Sign On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274688/using-one-asp-net-membership-database-with-multiple-applications-single-sign-on)